# estoy tratando de ver los detalles de un articulo en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Cuando hago las peticiones a la base de datos me da este error, estoy en la version 5.5 de laravel, no se si es un error de sintaxis o es algo que no se como hacer, porque si uso un First() en vez del groupBy me lanza otra exepcion, diciendo que es necesario un groupBY

```html
 public function show($id)
    {
        $ingreso = DB::table('ingreso as i')
        ->join('persona as p', 'i.idproveedor', '=', 'p.idpersona')
        ->join('detalle_ingreso as di', 'i.idingreso', '=', 'di.idingreso')
        ->select('i.idingreso', 'i.fecha_hora', 'p.nombre', 'i.tipo_comprobante', 'i.serie_comprobante', 'i.num_comprobante', 'i.impuesto' , 'i.estado', DB::raw('sum(di.cantidad*precio_compra) as total'))
        ->where('i.idingreso', '=', $id)
        ->groupBy('i.idingreso', 'i.fecha_hora', 'p.nombre', 'i.tipo_comprobante', 'i.serie_comprobante', 'i.num_comprobante', 'i.impuesto' , 'i.estado');
                
        $detalles = DB::table('detalle_ingreso as di')
        ->join('articulo as a','di.idarticulo','=','a.idarticulo')
        ->select('a.nombre as articulo','di.cantidad','di.precio_compra','di.precio_venta')
        ->where('di.idingreso','=',$id)
        ->get();

        return redirect()->route("ingreso.show", ["ingreso" => $ingreso, "detalles" => $detalles]);
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin el código relacionado a la consulta que tratas de llevar a cabo no lo vamos a poder saber tampoco, por favor lee [ask], edita y amplia tu pregunta

Comment: Te falta el `get()` o `first()` después del `groupBy()` de `$ingreso`.

Answer (score -1):

```
      ->where('i.idingreso','=',$id)
      ->groupBy('i.idingreso','i.fecha_hora','p.nombre','i.tipo_comprobante','i.serie_comprobante', 'i.num_comprobante','i.impuesto','i.estado')
      ->first();
```

mete el groupBy es lo que falta

Comment: ¿por qué debe agrupar?, considera explicar tu código para que tu aporte eleve su calidad